# How do you make a textbox input autcomplete/autosuggest that shows the first match inside the textbox, rather than a list?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've found several samples of autocomplete/autosuggest, but the way they implement it is by showing a list below the textbox that you later need to click or select. I'd like to show the closest match inside the textbox itself as the user is typing, so that they can later press tab (or whatever) to fill the rest of the entry.

I think I got the logic down on how to do this in Javascript (via Vue JS), but I cannot figure out how this would be displayed inside the input. The suggestion would be slightly dimmer in colour, like the text you see on a "placeholder", and will be overwritten as the user keeps typing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just position it absolutely, with a low z-index.

```
<div class="container">
      <input v-model="value" @keyup.prevent="autofill"></input>
      <div class="suggested">
      {{suggested}}
      </div>
</div>
```

```
input {
  border: 4px solid #e3e3e3;
  padding:10px;
  width:100%;
}
.container {
  width:50%;
  margin: auto;
  position:relative;
}
.suggested {
  position:absolute;
  top:25px;
  left:25px;
  color:#e3e3e3;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

working example: https://codepen.io/ellisdod/pen/mdJayxo